# I get multi-class error when trying to use roc_auc_score from scikit-learn even though both arrays are 1D

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Even if I put the multi class argument, the next error is about the dimension:

```
numpy.exceptions.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

This is the original run:

```
Number of gates for each filter:  784
1591it [00:15, 102.42it/s]
ACC TRAIN 0 valid 0.5849989190888902
RMSE:  0
[0 2 1 ... 2 0 1]
[ 0.77736357  0.3725196   1.01126466 ...  0.26738772 -0.063023
  0.77434902]
The y_label is 1D.
The pred_proba is 1D.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Fairness\infer_truth_tables.py", line 359, in <module>
    print("ROC (%)", 100 * roc_auc_score(y_label, pred_proba)) #y_true, #y_score
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_param_validation.py", line 211, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_ranking.py", line 619, in roc_auc_score
    raise ValueError("multi_class must be in ('ovo', 'ovr')")
ValueError: multi_class must be in ('ovo', 'ovr')
```

I am using scikit-learn v1.3 (latest).

Comment: You need to post your *code*, not merely its output; please see how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

In the multi-class case, `y_pred` must contain the probabilities for *all* classes, so it needs to be a k-D array where k is the number of classes (`y_true` can still be a 1D array).

Using the multiclass example from the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html), with the iris data (3-class, as seems to be your case, too):

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
clf = LogisticRegression(solver="liblinear").fit(X, y)
roc_auc_score(y, clf.predict_proba(X), multi_class='ovr')
# result:
0.9913333333333334
```

Notice that the `y_pred` here is

```
clf.predict_proba(X)
# result:

array([[8.78030305e-01, 1.21958900e-01, 1.07949250e-05],
       [7.97058292e-01, 2.02911413e-01, 3.02949242e-05],
       [8.51997665e-01, 1.47976480e-01, 2.58550858e-05],
       [8.23406019e-01, 1.76536159e-01, 5.78217704e-05],
       [8.96034973e-01, 1.03953836e-01, 1.11907339e-05],
       [9.26234254e-01, 7.37527845e-02, 1.29612594e-05],
       [8.94096848e-01, 1.05863935e-01, 3.92166195e-05],
       [8.60034410e-01, 1.39946715e-01, 1.88751124e-05],
       [8.01028643e-01, 1.98886755e-01, 8.46025595e-05],
       [7.92662392e-01, 2.07312003e-01, 2.56051563e-05],
       [8.90486112e-01, 1.09507726e-01, 6.16178069e-06],
       [8.61800668e-01, 1.38164963e-01, 3.43688884e-05],
       [7.85364369e-01, 2.14608265e-01, 2.73660893e-05],
       [8.33122325e-01, 1.66845600e-01, 3.20746459e-05],
       [9.27105079e-01, 7.28939564e-02, 9.65025075e-07],
       [9.64209783e-01, 3.57879589e-02, 2.25815135e-06],
       [9.40244677e-01, 5.97504819e-02, 4.84124978e-06],
       [8.90383643e-01, 1.09602199e-01, 1.41584311e-05],
       [8.94996432e-01, 1.04996803e-01, 6.76561305e-06],
       [9.22818333e-01, 7.71698511e-02, 1.18163279e-05],
       [8.28168845e-01, 1.71815986e-01, 1.51697603e-05],
       [9.21162903e-01, 7.88192700e-02, 1.78269001e-05],
       [9.25830555e-01, 7.41609901e-02, 8.45537828e-06],
       [8.66425048e-01, 1.33506832e-01, 6.81196349e-05],
       [8.39579062e-01, 1.60348453e-01, 7.24851587e-05],
       [7.74387849e-01, 2.25570742e-01, 4.14089912e-05],
       [8.80142212e-01, 1.19816026e-01, 4.17624967e-05],
       [8.68142117e-01, 1.31846325e-01, 1.15578057e-05],
       [8.57981539e-01, 1.42008075e-01, 1.03858266e-05],
       [8.30136546e-01, 1.69809392e-01, 5.40618507e-05],
       [8.05488891e-01, 1.94459296e-01, 5.18131431e-05],
       [8.70807410e-01, 1.29176481e-01, 1.61085791e-05],
       [9.33140300e-01, 6.68559138e-02, 3.78606175e-06],
       [9.45563050e-01, 5.44349664e-02, 1.98362125e-06],
       [8.09104104e-01, 1.90862024e-01, 3.38721089e-05],
       [8.45406669e-01, 1.54581407e-01, 1.19235303e-05],
       [8.67845100e-01, 1.32150712e-01, 4.18747716e-06],
       [8.87815808e-01, 1.12174014e-01, 1.01779750e-05],
       [8.29173320e-01, 1.70768916e-01, 5.77645348e-05],
       [8.55787332e-01, 1.44196849e-01, 1.58184132e-05],
       [8.99021427e-01, 1.00965368e-01, 1.32051891e-05],
       [6.87609664e-01, 3.12227285e-01, 1.63051259e-04],
       [8.64687415e-01, 1.35268656e-01, 4.39289817e-05],
       [9.15725060e-01, 8.42126724e-02, 6.22672835e-05],
       [9.14838651e-01, 8.51196936e-02, 4.16549750e-05],
       [8.18139824e-01, 1.81812290e-01, 4.78858984e-05],
       [9.08802553e-01, 9.11858864e-02, 1.15610231e-05],
       [8.49522363e-01, 1.50438207e-01, 3.94305065e-05],
       [8.94050930e-01, 1.05941728e-01, 7.34243342e-06],
       [8.49541191e-01, 1.50441863e-01, 1.69463468e-05],
       [2.96005280e-02, 8.61269712e-01, 1.09129760e-01],
       [3.73566204e-02, 7.05998640e-01, 2.56644739e-01],
       [1.17188234e-02, 7.49180286e-01, 2.39100891e-01],
       [1.32329304e-02, 6.52615267e-01, 3.34151803e-01],
       [1.09261044e-02, 6.99751683e-01, 2.89322212e-01],
       [1.07475746e-02, 5.83523451e-01, 4.05728975e-01],
       [2.15536329e-02, 5.37367355e-01, 4.41079012e-01],
       [1.07796125e-01, 7.69764033e-01, 1.22439842e-01],
       [1.75648125e-02, 8.28471633e-01, 1.53963555e-01],
       [3.31000964e-02, 5.28434824e-01, 4.38465079e-01],
       [2.90940948e-02, 7.73621445e-01, 1.97284460e-01],
       [4.09552911e-02, 6.19782220e-01, 3.39262489e-01],
       [1.93064131e-02, 8.80411764e-01, 1.00281823e-01],
       [8.71111808e-03, 5.97119816e-01, 3.94169066e-01],
       [1.66935421e-01, 7.13419402e-01, 1.19645177e-01],
       [4.71498045e-02, 8.44539593e-01, 1.08310603e-01],
       [1.22914643e-02, 4.23221121e-01, 5.64487414e-01],
       [3.81169424e-02, 8.51071811e-01, 1.10811246e-01],
       [3.08282665e-03, 5.97230434e-01, 3.99686739e-01],
       [3.56967896e-02, 8.09665888e-01, 1.54637322e-01],
       [6.24630686e-03, 2.71625774e-01, 7.22127920e-01],
       [5.76762120e-02, 8.20642529e-01, 1.21681259e-01],
       [1.95123191e-03, 5.34646840e-01, 4.63401928e-01],
       [8.72420378e-03, 7.05586974e-01, 2.85688822e-01],
       [3.66059277e-02, 8.39899070e-01, 1.23495002e-01],
       [3.58881987e-02, 8.29637761e-01, 1.34474040e-01],
       [8.07402014e-03, 7.78160148e-01, 2.13765831e-01],
       [4.63306706e-03, 5.23640589e-01, 4.71726344e-01],
       [1.33399755e-02, 5.63479864e-01, 4.23180160e-01],
       [1.27116911e-01, 8.32931303e-01, 3.99517868e-02],
       [3.58104443e-02, 8.04137922e-01, 1.60051633e-01],
       [5.00338269e-02, 8.47112731e-01, 1.02853442e-01],
       [5.65602460e-02, 8.12180151e-01, 1.31259603e-01],
       [1.22599564e-03, 3.99303559e-01, 5.99470445e-01],
       [1.03590059e-02, 3.64040618e-01, 6.25600376e-01],
       [4.19275526e-02, 4.76596179e-01, 4.81476269e-01],
       [1.89485725e-02, 7.46442362e-01, 2.34609065e-01],
       [6.99117780e-03, 7.57889791e-01, 2.35119031e-01],
       [5.57046086e-02, 6.67601538e-01, 2.76693853e-01],
       [2.10040955e-02, 6.63077802e-01, 3.15918102e-01],
       [8.95358807e-03, 6.00417365e-01, 3.90629047e-01],
       [1.51849311e-02, 6.32849506e-01, 3.51965563e-01],
       [3.45147534e-02, 7.99531968e-01, 1.65953279e-01],
       [9.08897829e-02, 7.96946159e-01, 1.12164059e-01],
       [1.97905433e-02, 6.41453325e-01, 3.38756132e-01],
       [4.79463041e-02, 7.31607407e-01, 2.20446289e-01],
       [3.43786632e-02, 6.77926137e-01, 2.87695200e-01],
       [3.36527705e-02, 7.97759624e-01, 1.68587605e-01],
       [2.53176193e-01, 6.92330452e-01, 5.44933549e-02],
       [3.62293481e-02, 7.04841253e-01, 2.58929399e-01],
       [1.88584495e-04, 1.46372620e-01, 8.53438796e-01],
       [8.14030927e-04, 2.93447140e-01, 7.05738829e-01],
       [2.79000675e-04, 3.30239074e-01, 6.69481925e-01],
       [4.58010577e-04, 3.38339912e-01, 6.61202077e-01],
       [2.53414333e-04, 2.55714364e-01, 7.44032222e-01],
       [6.04096412e-05, 3.82917567e-01, 6.17022023e-01],
       [2.06351241e-03, 2.79806199e-01, 7.18130289e-01],
       [1.23117341e-04, 4.24934867e-01, 5.74942016e-01],
       [1.59900415e-04, 4.23615517e-01, 5.76224583e-01],
       [3.59862147e-04, 1.50750096e-01, 8.48890041e-01],
       [3.01206048e-03, 2.76860976e-01, 7.20126963e-01],
       [6.46894500e-04, 3.55513745e-01, 6.43839361e-01],
       [6.83917045e-04, 2.98193127e-01, 7.01122956e-01],
       [6.32648495e-04, 2.95768393e-01, 7.03598958e-01],
       [6.18169454e-04, 1.72425080e-01, 8.26956751e-01],
       [1.10759845e-03, 1.71476162e-01, 8.27416239e-01],
       [8.01410072e-04, 3.48670193e-01, 6.50528397e-01],
       [1.94621163e-04, 2.37367517e-01, 7.62437862e-01],
       [1.30336939e-05, 4.20322938e-01, 5.79664028e-01],
       [6.79992906e-04, 4.70615141e-01, 5.28704866e-01],
       [5.08108403e-04, 2.23925960e-01, 7.75565932e-01],
       [1.35050479e-03, 2.28520314e-01, 7.70129181e-01],
       [3.81823791e-05, 4.28497457e-01, 5.71464360e-01],
       [2.05513546e-03, 4.00468848e-01, 5.97476017e-01],
       [6.82426332e-04, 2.35908846e-01, 7.63408727e-01],
       [4.56419242e-04, 3.97832643e-01, 6.01710938e-01],
       [3.20523990e-03, 3.83614307e-01, 6.13180453e-01],
       [3.43775514e-03, 3.26737167e-01, 6.69825078e-01],
       [3.02387244e-04, 2.97387632e-01, 7.02309980e-01],
       [6.75745429e-04, 5.11618205e-01, 4.87706049e-01],
       [1.61467286e-04, 4.28548421e-01, 5.71290112e-01],
       [6.45929280e-04, 3.44604031e-01, 6.54750040e-01],
       [2.77285011e-04, 2.76854155e-01, 7.22868560e-01],
       [2.07366663e-03, 4.91252488e-01, 5.06673845e-01],
       [3.54387390e-04, 4.43072814e-01, 5.56572798e-01],
       [1.82369410e-04, 3.41966166e-01, 6.57851465e-01],
       [6.38376976e-04, 1.26565896e-01, 8.72795727e-01],
       [9.25543173e-04, 3.20314461e-01, 6.78759996e-01],
       [4.31282889e-03, 3.17469066e-01, 6.78218105e-01],
       [1.17132006e-03, 3.00300498e-01, 6.98528182e-01],
       [4.50214297e-04, 2.00800053e-01, 7.98749733e-01],
       [2.16404408e-03, 2.47613735e-01, 7.50222221e-01],
       [8.14030927e-04, 2.93447140e-01, 7.05738829e-01],
       [2.93581038e-04, 2.23396734e-01, 7.76309685e-01],
       [4.55252466e-04, 1.52049282e-01, 8.47495466e-01],
       [1.16468551e-03, 2.32330147e-01, 7.66505167e-01],
       [9.20404029e-04, 3.79262991e-01, 6.19816605e-01],
       [1.46454826e-03, 2.97584288e-01, 7.00951164e-01],
       [1.10985568e-03, 1.29831848e-01, 8.69058297e-01],
       [1.69378510e-03, 2.79973392e-01, 7.18332822e-01]])
```

i.e. a 3D array (for 3 classes).

Apart from the above, your shown results for `y_pred`, `[ 0.77736357  0.3725196   1.01126466 ...  0.26738772 -0.063023   0.77434902]`, look puzzling, as they contain both negative numbers and values greater than 1, which should not be the case (`predict_proba` returns probabilities between 0 and 1, and `roc_auc_score` is meant to be used with such inputs, not arbitrary ones).